# Combine 4 cells in a table

Tags: tables, multirow

Here is a simple table.

I want to merge 4 cells. I want to combine the three "this" cells area in this table.
I thought I have to use `multirow` and `multicolum` at same time.
However, I could not find how to use it.

If possible, could you post the modified LaTeX source code?

[image: picture of table]

My LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ph]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Raaa (k)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{C ()} \\
\hhline{~----}
 & 3.3 & 2.5 & 1 & 0.5 \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Raaa (k)} & \multirow{2}{*}{this} & this & 0.5 & 0.6\\
\hhline{~~~--}            &                       & this & 0.7 & 1.2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{R, C ripple size}
\label{T:peak}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Next time you ask a question, please add a *full* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). As you just posted the table, Werner had to find out that you're using the packages `multirow` and `hhline` in order to solve your problem. That's just unnecessary work. Also, it'd be nice if you added a picture to this question, now as you have some reputation points and the [new user restrictions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user) have been removed from your account.

Comment: @doncherry He's not gonna do it, the question is popular and one of the top google hits for the request. I did my best at editing, would you mind reviewing ?

Answer (score 54):

Both rows should contain a `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}`, and the first row should contain a nested `\multirow{2}{*}{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ph]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Raaa (k)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{C ()} \\
    \hhline{~----}
    & 3.3 & 2.5 & 1 & 0.5 \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Raaa (k)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{this}} & 0.5 & 0.6\\
    \hhline{~~~--}            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                      & 0.7 & 1.2 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{R, C ripple size}
  \label{T:peak}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Since `\multicolumn` overrides any of the set column alignments (including the vertical rules), you have to respecify everything. Hence the use of `c|` to `c`enter the contents and end it with a vertical rule.

Also note how I used `\centering` instead of the `center` environment (`\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}`). This allows for better vertical spacing around elements in your document. Consider reading the following post: [Should I use center or centering for figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures)

Answer (score 22):

Vertical lines burn my eyes. Tables almost always look better without them. Here's a version that uses `booktabs` for nice horizontal lines.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Raaa (k)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{C ()} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5} & 3.3 & 2.5 & 1 & 0.5 \\
  \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Raaa (k)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{this}} & 0.5 & 0.6 \\
    \cmidrule{4-5}            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}                      & 0.7 & 1.2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{R, C ripple size}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (however, as many people on this site, I recommend constructing such tables with the design of `booktabs`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ph]
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c|c}[hlines]
\Block{2-1}{Raaa (k)} & \Block{1-4}{C ()} \\
                      & 3.3               & 2.5  & 1   & 0.5 \\
\Block{2-1}{Raaa (k)} & \Block{2-1}{this} & this & 0.5 & 0.6 \\
                      &                   & this & 0.7 & 1.2 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{R, C ripple size}
\label{T:peak}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]