# How can this table be created in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I'm new to LaTeX, and just want to ask how the following table may be created using LaTeX:

[image]

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Jake (and closers) This one has `multirow`, so slightly different.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Ah yes, you're right.

Comment: @Simplicity: [Merging cells in a column of a table](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multirow)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35126/combine-4-cells-in-a-table/35127#35127