# How can the following table be created in LaTeX

Tags: tables, tex-core

I have asked this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149152/how-can-this-table-be-created-in-latex?noredirect=1#comment338983_149152), and asking it once again, as it was marked as `duplicate`, although it is *different* from the links that were pointed to be the same as the question.

So, how can I create a table that looks like the following using LaTex?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: If a question is closed as duplicate and you think it should not be, you can _edit the question_ to clarify any differences. Do not just ask the same question again. this is still essentially a duplicate, the requested table is almost exactly like the one linked. If you have a specific question about a specific difference, ask about _that_.