# Splitting a row to two rows in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I have the following table in LaTex:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
first & second & third  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
A & C & E \\
B & D & F \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
```

For `C` and `D`, how can I split each of those two rows to two rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to obtain (a skeleton of) a tabular from your question [How can the following table be created in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149227/how-can-the-following-table-be-created-in-latex), the solution may be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*7{p{15mm}|}}
\hline
&&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{}\\
\cline{3-7}
&&&&&&\\
\hline
&&&&&&\\
\cline{2-7}
&&&&&&\\
\hline
&&&&&&\\
\cline{2-7}
&&&&&&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If it is an independent question, we can use tabulars inside tabulars, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
first & second & third  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
A & 
\begin{tabular}{c}C \\CC\end{tabular}
& E \\
B & 
\begin{tabular}{c}D \\DD\end{tabular}
& F \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]