# How can I merge 3 cells?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to do something like this
[image]

My code is as follows

```
\begin{table}[H]
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
 \centering
\caption{Reduct size}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Data&\multicolumn{6}{c|}{NRB}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{CA}&CFF&CVF\\
\cline{2-10}
&&&&&&&0.75&0.85&0.95&&\\
\cline{2-7}
%\hline
&0.2&0.4&0.6&0.2&0.4&0.6&&&&&\\\hline
%\cline{2-3}
D_1&7(2)&14(6)&8(3)&7(2)&13(5)&8(3)&13(5)&17(7)&23(8)&3(1)&10(4)\\
 \hline
 D_2&12(6)&1(1)&1(1)&22(9)&1(1)&1(1)&11(5)&17(8)&26(10)&14(7)&5(2)\\\hline
%\cline{2-3}1
D_3&5(1)&8(3)&15(7)&6(2)&18(9)&16(8)&10(5)&13(6)&15(7)&5(1)&9(4)\\

  \hline
  D_4&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&9(3)&11(4)&13(5)&7(2)&9(3)\\   

 \hline
D_5&7(4)&10(6)&1(1)&7(4)&10(6)&1(1)&9(5)&12(7)&16(8)&4(2)&5(3)\\\hline

  \end{tabular}
  %}
    \label{tab:subset_trad}

\end{table}
```

BUT the output is as follow [image]

So how can i merge the cells under NRB into two cells as in the first figure?

Comment: ? Why don't you use \multicolumn again?

Comment: please show me how.... i have a bit knowledge about that.... Thanks for your answer

Comment: But you are already using `\multicolumn{3}{c|}{CA}` to merge the three cells with CA, so where is your problem?

Comment: A more general discussion on cell merging is available from [Combine 4 cells in a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35126/5764).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `D_1` and so on should be D with subscript 1 and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}%[H]
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
 \centering
\caption{Reduct size}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Data&\multicolumn{6}{c|}{NRB}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{CA}&CFF&CVF\\
\cline{2-10}
%&&&&&&&0.75&0.85&0.95&&\\
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{0.1}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{0.2}&&&0.75&0.85&0.95&&\\
\cline{2-7}
%\hline
&0.2&0.4&0.6&0.2&0.4&0.6&&&&&\\\hline
%\cline{2-3}
$D_1$&7(2)&14(6)&8(3)&7(2)&13(5)&8(3)&13(5)&17(7)&23(8)&3(1)&10(4)\\
 \hline
 $D_2$&12(6)&1(1)&1(1)&22(9)&1(1)&1(1)&11(5)&17(8)&26(10)&14(7)&5(2)\\\hline
%\cline{2-3}1
$D_3$&5(1)&8(3)&15(7)&6(2)&18(9)&16(8)&10(5)&13(6)&15(7)&5(1)&9(4)\\

  \hline
 $ D_4$&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&9(3)&11(4)&13(5)&7(2)&9(3)\\   

 \hline
$D_5$&7(4)&10(6)&1(1)&7(4)&10(6)&1(1)&9(5)&12(7)&16(8)&4(2)&5(3)\\\hline

  \end{tabular}
  %}
    \label{tab:subset_trad}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions: Don't use that `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{...` construct to make your table fit to text width.  Drop using vertical lines in your table.  Put `\label` after `\caption`.  Always post complete working examples.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \footnotesize
  \centering
  \caption{Reduct size}
  \label{tab:subset_trad}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lccccccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    Data & \multicolumn{6}{c}{NRB} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CA} & CFF & CVF\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-7}\cmidrule(l){8-10}
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{0.4} & 0.75 & 0.85 & 0.95\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
         & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}%
    \cmidrule(lr){5-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-8}%
    \cmidrule(lr){9-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-10}\cmidrule(lr){11-11}\cmidrule(l){12-12}
    D\_1&7(2)&14(6)&8(3)&7(2)&13(5)&8(3)&13(5)&17(7)&23(8)&3(1)&10(4) \\
    D\_2&12(6)&1(1)&1(1)&22(9)&1(1)&1(1)&11(5)&17(8)&26(10)&14(7)&5(2)\\
    D\_3&5(1)&8(3)&15(7)&6(2)&18(9)&16(8)&10(5)&13(6)&15(7)&5(1)&9(4)\\
    D\_4&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&4(1)&9(3)&11(4)&13(5)&7(2)&9(3)\\   
    D\_5&7(4)&10(6)&1(1)&7(4)&10(6)&1(1)&9(5)&12(7)&16(8)&4(2)&5(3)\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image]