# How do I make table cells that span more than one column or row?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

[image: Picture of a book page with a table printed on it, as well as some text.]

I tried this code but the border lines are not deleted:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.6in}|p{0.3in}|p{0.9in}|p{0.9in}|p{0.8in}|} \hline 
 &                                                   &  & $P_{mot}$ &  \\ \hline 
$P_{batt}$ &  & S & M & H \\ \hline 
 & S & S & Z & VS \\ \hline 
SOC & M & M & Z & H \\ \hline 
 & H & M & Z & H \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

How do I delete the border of cells?

Comment: Why not use a different (better) representation? Something that uses [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM380.png)?

Comment: You might have a use for https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ to generate your latex tables, I often use this tool.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Okay i will consider those methods

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! In order to merge rows or columns, you need to use `\multirow` (which requires the `multirow` package) or `\multicolumn`, respectively. And if you nest them, you need to do it [in the right order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35127/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.6in}|p{0.3in}|p{0.9in}|p{0.9in}|p{0.8in}|} \hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$P_\mathrm{batt}$}} &                                                   
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$P_\mathrm{mot}$ }  \\ \cline{3-5} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}   & S & M & H \\ \cline{1-5} 
\multirow{3}{*}{SOC} & S & S & Z & VS \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & M & M & Z & H \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & H & M & Z & H \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The initial `|` in `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$P_\mathrm{mot}$ }` should be deleted, otherwise it is printed twice.

Comment: Yeah am not aware of all the methods. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 12):

With `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` you can reach what you need.

I have also created a new column type for centering the cell contents and redefined `\arraystretch` to have more vertical space between rows.

However, I would suggest you to get rid of the vertical rules and use `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
Your table:\vspace{10pt}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.6in}|C{0.3in}|C{0.4in}|C{0.4in}|C{0.4in}|} \hline 
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$P_{batt}$}}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$P_{mot}$}   \\ \cline{3-5} 
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}  & S & M & H \\ \hline 
  & S & S & Z & VS \\ \cline{2-5} 
 SOC & M & M & Z & H \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & H & M & Z & H \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10pt}My suggestion:\vspace{10pt}

\begin{tabular}{lc*{3}{C{1.5em}}}
\toprule 
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$P_{batt}$}}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$P_{mot}$}   \\ \cmidrule{3-5} 
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{}  & S & M & H \\ \midrule 
 & S & S & Z & VS \\ \cmidrule(l){2-5} 
SOC & M & M & Z & H \\ \cmidrule(l){2-5} 
 & H & M & Z & H \\ 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Am a beginner in latex, that's why. I don;t know about this booktabs. Anyway thanks for the suggestion, I will look through it.

Answer (score 8):

Whatever applies to each item in a column should go in the column header. Here's my proposal:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ @{} *{4}{w{c}{3em}} @{} }
\toprule
$P_{\mathrm{batt}}$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$P_{\mathrm{mot}}$} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-4}
SOC & S & M & H \\
\midrule 
S & S & Z & VS \\
M & M & Z & H \\
H & M & Z & H \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Rule based of fuzzy logic control}

\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]