# How to create table with divided cells

Tags: tables, tex-core

I need to create table in a TeX as shown below[image]

I tried

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
  \hline
  \textbf{Section 1} & \textbf{Section 2} & \textbf{Section 3} \\
  \hline
  1. Point & \begin{tabular}{c}
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{Lorem ispum}\\\hline
       Lorem ispum \\\hline
       Lorem ispum \\\hline
    \end{tabular} & Lorem ispum \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

But I don't know a way to do this properly. Not only I need to divide cells, but their lines should match with lines in other column like shown in the pricture. Any solutions would be appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You cannot divide cells but join cells. For joint cells of different rows, search about the `multirow` package.

Comment: See [Combine 4 cells in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35126/5764).

Answer (score 1):

I used `tabularray` package to create the table. Does this help you?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,amsmath}
\newcounter{tabitem}%<--for numbering inside the table
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\stepcounter{tabitem}\makebox[21pt][r]{\arabic{tabitem}.\;\,}}%<--how the numbering inside the table will look and step.

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[3cm,l]Q[4cm,l]Q[7cm,l]},rows={1cm,m},vlines,hlines,cell{1}{1-3}={c},row{2}={5cm,h},row{3}={3cm,h},row{5}={2cm,h},row{6}={3cm,h},cell{2}{1}={c=1,r=2}{l},cell{4}{1}={c=1,r=3}{h}}
        \textbf{Section 1} & \textbf{Section 2}  & \textbf{Section 3}\\
        \tabitem Point 1   & Lorem ipsum         & - Lorem Ipsum     \\
                           & Lorem ipsum         & - Lorem Ipsum     \\
         \tabitem Point 2  & Lorem ipsum         & - Lorem Ipsum     \\
                           & Lorem ipsum         & - Lorem Ipsum     \\
                           & Lorem ipsum         & - Lorem Ipsum     \\                   
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```