# Latex table creation with different cells

Tags: tables, tabularx

I would like to create the following table in the Latex

[image]

How can I create one?

Comment: This is a general question about merging cells. See [Combine 4 cells in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35126/5764) (possible duplicate) for a discussion on merging cells (horizontally or vertically).

Comment: You might want to consider reading about table creation in LaTeX. For this you could read the [lesson Tables of LearnLaTeX](https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{X[l]*{9}{X[c]}}[hvlines]
\Block{1-10}{...} \\
xyz & \Block{1-3}{...} &&& \Block{1-3}{...} &&& \Block{1-3}{...} \\
abc & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
def \\
ghi \\
jkl \\
mno \\
pqr \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

You've provided a sketch of the desired overall appearance, but you've left a lot of design aspects unspecified. E.g., should automatic line-wrapping be enabled, for all cells or for just a few? Should the cell contents be left-aligned, centered, right-aligned, something else? Should the 9 data columns all have the same width? The sketch you posted suggests that the left-hand or "header" column should be about 20% wider than the data columns; is this impression correct? Should the table be typeset in portrait or landscape mode?

I had to address some of these issues to come up with the following table. E.g., because the table has 10 columns, it is typeset in landscape mode; its target width is the width of the (rotated) text block; and automatic line breaking is enabled in all cells (except those formed by `\multicolumn` directives). Please advise if you'd rather apply different settings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}% or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabualarx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' and '\Centering' macros
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}   % for a more open look
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt} % default: 0.4pt

\begin{table}
%\caption{Place the caption here} % add if needed
%\smallskip

% Make the contents of first col. left-aligned, and 
% the contents of the other nine columns centered.
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L{1.18}|*{9}{C{0.98}|}}

\hline
\multicolumn{10}{|c|}{\dots} \\ % full-width header cell
\hline
xyz   & \multicolumn{3}{ c|}{\dots} % 3 header cells that span 3 columns each
      & \multicolumn{3}{ c|}{\dots}
      & \multicolumn{3}{ c|}{\dots} \\ 
\hline
%% now for the "body" of the table
abc   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
def   & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
ghi   & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
jkl   & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
mno   & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
pqr   & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```